# Salesforce Azure AD automatic provisioning

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce, provisioning

I am trying automatic provisioning from Azure Active Directory to salesforce. The single sign on is working for salesforce but automatic provisioning is giving error. In salesforce I chose JIT provisioning with SAML JIT Handler but provisioning is giving the following error.

> ErrorCode: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST ErrorMessage: Locale: bad value for restricted picklist field: en

Try to System.debug in the Handler but it seems that this code is not been executed. Nothing in the logs.

[image]

Comment: You generated an Apex class with https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_Auth_SamlJitHandler.htm, correct? Populated it in SSO config and set "run as" some System Administrator? Go to Setup -> Debug Logs, start tracking that Sysadmin (not the user that's trying to log in). There's really nothing captured?

Comment: The log is empty. My assumption is that the provisioning is not sending the correct data for salesforce to create user. Salesforce is expecting user.email and azure is sending user.mail like wise the attributes are not matching with salesforce. How can I check what parameters are coming from azure. This is my first time with azure active directory. I can not see the option Sync only assigned users and groups. Either Azure updated the process or free version is not showing the options.

Comment: It's strange that it's empty. I'd expect either no log at all (go to SF Setup -> Single Sign On and the "saml assertion validator" would hopefully contain what basic validations it died on even before hitting your code). If you really do have a log... Can you post the source code of your class? And what debug log levels did you use... Are you able to pass the training challenge at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_login/identity_login_sso, then tweak it to use your class and see what explodes?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill LocaleSidKey with 'en', but that is not a valid choice. 'en_us' would be a valid choice.